# What kind of mechanism can be used to rotate a part in 180 degrees (Ψ (yaw)) and 30degrees in  (pitch) direction?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-theory, microelectronics, machine-design, machine-elements

Let's say we have a flat object. We are asked to create some mechanism so that the part can rotate in the shown angles above. What mechanisms can be used?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gimbals are the classic solution for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal 
And if you don't need any roll, you can omit one of the gimbal rings, in which case a **pan/tilt** mechanism is sufficient (often sold for photography.) You might look for a gimballed gyroscope toy and start with that. (Flight quality gimbals are *expensive*.)

Comment: Link only answers are considered poor on this stack, due to link rot.

Comment: (1) it's a Wikipedia link to a non-controversial subject, so I suspect it'll be there longer than anybody reading, and (b) even a dictionary will return something useful for the user if they know the name of the mechanism. YMMV

Comment: 1 and 2 or A and B? why mix?

Comment: @SolarMike He has not yet come up with number 2. I guess the number one has two subsegment:)

Comment: @SamFarjamirad he started with (1) then used (b) ...

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry for confusion, i put a winky face at the end of my first comment, indeed difficult to decipher the tone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your head part on a neck globe with two pins protruding out and  screw that into a  sphere socket like a kids doll neck.

This spherical socket is threaded in a pitch that spirals around the sphere with the slope of 30 degrees over a half a turn and the two pins slide back and forth in this thread.